# Regex url pattern for django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views

I need to define an URL pattern for the below URL

```
http://myurl:8080/authentication/agent/newpassword/?resetPassword=textValue&agentCode=textValue
```

I tried the following but I get 404

```
url(r'^authentication/agent/newpassword/(?P<resetPassword>.+)(P<agentCode>.+)/$', passwordValidation),
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Error message that Im getting is

```
"GET /authentication/agent/newpassword/?resetPassword=textValue&agentCode=textValue HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't match query string in Django url pattern.

Use the following pattern:

```
url(r'^authentication/agent/newpassword/$', passwordValidation),
```

And in the view, use `request.GET` to get GET parameters:

```
def passwordValidation(request):
    resetPassword = request.GET.get('resetPassword', '')
    agentCode = request.GET.get('agentCode', '')
```

Comment: I'm trying to redirect from Paypal Payment Gateway to above mentioned URL but I always get 302 as status code. Anything I should do?

Comment: @syv, Could you update the question with the detail status/error information?

Comment: I got it. I put csrf validation as part of decorators. Thats is the issue.

Comment: @syv, Does removing the decorator solve your problem?